# Move 53,800+ files into 54 separate folders with ~1000 files each?

Tags: pop3, maildir, gmail

Trying to import 53,800+ individual files (messages) using Gmail's POP fetcher.

Gmail understandably refuses, giving the error: *"Too many messages to download. There are too many messages on the other server."*

The folder in question looks like similar to:

```
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203672790.V57I586f04M867101.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203676329.V57I586f22M520117.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203677194.V57I586f26M688004.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203679158.V57I586f2bM182864.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203680493.V57I586f33M740378.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203685837.V57I586f0bM835200.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203687920.V57I586f65M995884.mail.net:2,S
...
```

**Using the shell (tcsh, sh, etc. on FreeBSD), what one-line command can I type to split this directory full of files into separate folders so Gmail only sees 1000 messages at a time?**  Something with find or ls | xargs mv maybe.  Whatever is fastest.

The desired output directory would now look something like:

```
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203672790.V57I586f04M867101.mail.net:2,S
/usr/home/customer/Maildir/cur/1203676329.V57I586f22M520117.mail.net:2,S
...
/usr/home/customer/set1/ (contains messages 1-1000)
/usr/home/customer/set2/ (contains messages 1001-2000)
/usr/home/customer/set3/ (etc.)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a one-liner, but you could copy chunks like this (in csh):

```
foreach file (`ls | head -n 1000`)
mv $file /tmp/new/dir
end
```

I'm not 100% sure that pipe will work with the number of files you've got, but it's worth a shot. Also, you might be able to do 500 at a time with this command, just change that 1000 to 500.

Comment: in bash: `for file in (`ls | head -n 1000`) do mv $file /tmp/new/dir; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
count=target=0;

find srcdir/ -type f |
    while read file; do

        count=$((count+1));
        target=$((count/10000));

        [ -d $target ] || mkdir $target

        echo mv "$file" $target; #remove the 'echo' if you like what you see
    done
```

collapsed to a single line (and with the 'echo' safeguard removed):

```
count=target=0; find srcdir/ -type f | while read file; do count=$((count+1)); target=$((count/10000)); [ -d $target ] || mkdir $target; mv "$file" $target; done
```

This isn't the fastest but it's clean.  this solution avoids parsing the output of 'ls' http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and quotes the references to "$file" otherwise files with abnormal names (as Maildir files often are) would break the code.  For example if any of the files have spaces or semicolons then referencing $file without quotes isn't going to get you far (most of the time)

Read more about quoting: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words